# Elasticsearch sort by values in array

Tags: elasticsearch

Each of my records in Elasticsearch has an array of objects that looks like this:

```json
{
  "counts_by_year": [
    {
      "year": 2022,
      "works_count": 22523,
      "cited_by_count": 18054
    },
    {
      "year": 2021,
      "works_count": 32059,
      "cited_by_count": 24817
    },
    {
      "year": 2020,
      "works_count": 27210,
      "cited_by_count": 30238
    },
    {
      "year": 2019,
      "works_count": 22592,
      "cited_by_count": 33631
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is sort my records using the average of works_count where year is 2022 and year is 2021. Is this a case where I could use script based sorting? Or should I try to copy those values into a separate field and sort on that?

Edit - the mapping is:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        .
        .
        .
        "counts_by_year": {
          "properties": {
            "cited_by_count": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "works_count": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "year": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        },
        .
        .
        .
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

It depends.
Most likely yes, except if `count_by_year` is nested.

## Solution

Something along those lines should do the trick

```json
GET /_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['counts_by_year.works_count'].stream().mapToLong(x -> x).average().orElse(0);"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution (nested fields)

```json
PUT 74404793-2
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "counts_by_year": {
          "type": "nested", 
          "properties": {
            "cited_by_count": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "works_count": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "year": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

POST /74404793-2/_doc/
{
  "counts_by_year": [
    {
      "year": 2022,
      "works_count": 22523,
      "cited_by_count": 18054
    },
    {
      "year": 2021,
      "works_count": 32059,
      "cited_by_count": 24817
    },
    {
      "year": 2020,
      "works_count": 27210,
      "cited_by_count": 30238
    },
    {
      "year": 2019,
      "works_count": 22592,
      "cited_by_count": 33631
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using the `_source` to access the documents, it can severely impact the performances if you have big documents.

```json
GET 74404793-2/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
        params._source['counts_by_year']
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x['year'] > 2020)
        .mapToLong(x -> x['works_count'])
        .average().orElse(0);"""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks great. But I tried it and got the error "No field found for [counts_by_year] in mapping" even though counts_by_year definitely exists as an object type field.

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping ? Also you can try to [debug](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-debugging.html)

Comment: Ok I updated the question with the mapping! I will try debug as well.

Comment: I should have fixed it

Comment: Awesome thank you! Do you know how I could make it use the first two array values? Or only the array values that are from year 2021 and 2022?

Comment: Sure thing look at java filters

Comment: Ahhh no Casey... They need to be nested, this is going to be a bit more tricky